# ZF2 namespace and file system

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2, autoload

I have standard Application module in ZF2. It's configured by default, I didn't change anything. I just added some stuff:

```
module/
  Application/
    src/
      Application/
        Entity/
          Product/
            **Product.php**        
        Controller/
          **IndexController.php**
```

Product.php

```
namespace Application\Entity;

class Product
{

}
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Entity\Product;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       
        $product = new Product();   
    }
}
```

and I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Entity\Product' not found in \module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php on line 20
```

I use the same namespace, but it doesn't see it. Why?

**P.S: If I will change Product.php to be the following:**

```
namespace Application\Entity\Product;

class Product
{

}
```

then in the IndexController.php the following code will be working:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Entity\Product\Product;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       
        $product = new Product();   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I see that I have to follow PSR-0 standard, but can you explain a bit, does this standard come from php core OR it's just a funcitonality implemented in ZF2 framework?
Also can I change this behaviour? I'm not saying it's good, I just want to know how it actually works!
For example I want to use Application\Entity\Product and Product class is located in /Application/Entity/Product/Product.php. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put class `Product` in namespace `Application\Entity` then your directory structure should be

```
module/
  Application/
    src/
      Application/
        Entity/
          **Product.php**
```

see also the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

Comment: So does this standard come from php core OR it's just a funcitonality implemented in ZF2 framework?

Comment: It is not in PHP core but you will most likely find it in any framework, not just ZF2, this specific structure is for ZF2 though.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow PSR-2.
So the correct namespace would actually be 'Application\Entity\Product' for your current folder structure.
And that means you have to do

```
new \Application\Entity\Product\Product;
```

or

```
use Application\Entity\Product\Product;
new Product;
```

If you only want it to be Application\Entity\Product then you should move the file to the folder 'Entity'

Comment: The PSR regarding directory structure is actually PSR-0

Comment: So does this standard come from php core OR it's just a funcitonality implemented in ZF2 framework?